# Как sameSite защищает пользователя от утечки информации?

Tags: http, cookie, безопасность

Говорится, что атрибут `sameSite` защищает пользователя от утечки информации (к примеру, сбор статистики, персонализация рекламы).

Но мне не совсем понятно. К примеру:

1. Пользователь посещает какой-то сайт без `sameSite` защиты.
2. Сайт загружается, включая размещенный здесь рекламный баннер. При загрузке этого баннера делается HTTP-запрос к серверу "рекламного" сайта.

Вряд ли можно украсть чужие файлы cookie при сборе статистики. Я имею в виду, что любой файл cookie имеет свои собственные атрибуты `domain` и `path`, которые четко указывают куда именно будут отправлены куки. Получается, что во время этого HTTP-запроса только cookie самого же рекламного сайта могут быть загружены на сайт рекламодателя, если, конечно, они есть на устройстве пользователя.

Возникает вопрос: какой смысл собирать информацию о своем сайте на другом сайте? Этот сайт также благополучно может собирать статистику о себе и у себя.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос немного не понятный, но я попытаюсь ответить, не гарантирую что вы получите  ответ на свой вопрос.

---

Ну начнём с терминов чтобы не было путаницы:

сайт1 - "наш" сайт где мы хотим собирать информацию о пользователе

сайт2 - **НЕ** наш сайт с рекламой/аналитикой для сбора информации

---

И так, во-первых, сайт2 к примеру может собирать информацию с поисковиков и собирать информацию посещений, да вы можете этого делать через сайт1, но из-за этого на него  будет идти излишняя нагрузка, а та лишняя производительность сервера могла бы уйти на обеспечение более стабильной работы для пользователей. К тому же если сайт1 будет вести подробную аналитику через сайт2, то тогда на нагрузку попадёт только сеть пользователя, а сайт1 особо страдать из-за этого не будет, ну и если у сайта2 если такие возможности, то тогда можно будет вести статистику посещений и к этому всему подробную статистику о сессии пользователя на веб сайте.